# Convexity of the Riemann-zeta function without derivative

Tags: convex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Proving that the $\zeta$ function is convex on $(1,+\infty)$ is pretty simple if we use the derivative, but is there a  proof without using derivative? I'm allowed to use just the definition of the convexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint to the answer : a finite sum of convex functions is still convex.

what about an infinite sum ? ( $\zeta(\sigma)$ is convex for $\sigma \in ]1;\infty[$ but it is concave for $\sigma \in [0;1[$ )